# calling SecIdentitySearchCreate from python

Tags: pyobjc

I have

```
from ctypes import CDLL
Security = CDLL(....)

Security.SecIdentity.SearchCreate(0,0x80000000, ???)
```

I am not sure what to put as the last parameter. I tried byref(POINTER...)) but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
from ctypes import CDLL,c_void_p
Security = CDLL(....)
p = c_void_p(0)
Security.SecIdentity.SearchCreate(0,0x80000000, byref(p))
```